# How to call org-lint against org-mode file from command-line

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming, command-line-arguments, development

I am configuring a CI/CD pipeline to process org-mode files into documentation, source code, and other file formats.

I would like to add a call to `org-lint` to do basic syntax checking against org files as part pipeline.

Unfortunately I haven't be able get the command line to work.

I've tried the following commands:

```
emacs --batch -l org -f org-lint org-lint-notes.org

emacs --batch -l org --eval '(org-lint)' org-lint-notes.org
```

But both return the error below:

> Symbol’s function definition is void: org-lint

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help!

---

> **This code was tested using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   org-mode version:  9.1.2

Comment: I am not sure but I doubt that org 9.1.2 was shipped with emacs 25.2.1. I think it was some 8.X version. Could it be that you installed org 9.1.2 with `package-install`? In that case you need to add `-f package-initialize` to use orgmode 9.1.2 with `--batch`. Further note that you should load the buffer you want to lint before you call `-f org-lint`. You can test which org version you are using with `--batch` and without `package-initialize` by `emacs --batch -f org-version` on the command line.

Comment: Note further that you should not need `-l org` since `org-lint` as well as `org-version`are autoloaded.

Comment: @Tobias - Thank you! I completely forgot about loading `package-initialize` like `publish.el` does. I’ll do some research about loading buffer first and/or passing buffer name to `org-lint`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Calling `org-lint` against `org-mode` file from command-line

1. Create an `org-mode` file

   - For example, create a new file named `org-lint-ex1.org`

     ```
     * Using =org-lint= to Check org-mode Syntax
     ** Inside emacs

     1. Open org-mode file in emacs.

     2. Invoke =org-lint= command

        #+BEGIN_SRC 
          M-x org-lint
        #+END_SRC

         #+BEGIN_SR shell
          M-x org-lint
        #+END_SRC
     ```
2. Call `org-lint` from the command-line

   For example, to execute `org-lint` against the `org-lint-ex1.org` file use the following command:

   ```
   emacs --batch -f package-initialize --eval "(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
         (lambda ()  
             (let* ((file-name (current-buffer))
               (Col1 'Line)
               (Col2 'Trust)
               (Col3 'Warning)
               (lint-report (org-lint))
               )
             (princ (format \"file: %s\n%6s%6s%8s\n\" file-name Col1 Col2 Col3))
             (dolist (element lint-report)
              (setq report (car (cdr element)))
              (princ (format \"%6s%6s %7s\n\" (seq-elt report 0) (seq-elt report 1) (seq-elt report 2)))
             )
         )))" org-lint-ex1.org
   ```

   The output of the command should be similar to the following:

   ```
   file: org-lint-ex1.org
     Line Trust Warning
        8  high Missing language in source block
       12   low Possible incomplete block "#+BEGIN_SR shell"
       14   low Possible incomplete block "#+END_SRC"
   ```

> **Note:** If using emacs version less than 25.x.x, update script code to call `elt` instead of `seq-elt`.

---

> **This code was tested using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   org-mode version: 9.1.2

Comment: Say I want to use this in an automated manner, like a maybe a pre-commit hook or in a GitHub action for CI. How would I know if the command exited successfully or failed?

Comment: @PauloPhagula if you grep the output for numbers you'll be able detect when the output contains warnings. No numbers means the org file passed the org-lint test. Does that help?